# To strip a certain character out in Python

Tags: python

I have a string `str="[0,1,12]"`

What is the most efficent way to strip out the `"["` ,`"]"`, and the `","` only to leave the numbers as a `list` behind? I tried `.rstrip()`, but it only takes the characters at end of the string.

Comment: Where did you get this string from? If it's JSON, use the `json` module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Evaluate the string into a `list`:

```
from ast import literal_eval

numbers = literal_eval(your_string)
```

Comment: Semantics quibble--the string is already a Python object. But this is certainly the correct solution.

Comment: @KyleStrand: I have trouble writing this stuff out in plain English. How would you explain it?

Comment: @Blender: Evaluate the string into a `list`, perhaps? Of course, `literal_eval` isn't limited to that, but that's what the question asked about.